# magento - Can't retrieve entity config

Tags: magento

I have created two tables in my custom module. 1) wallets 2) sellerrequest
When I load   `Mage::getModel("wallets/wallets")->load();`  it works properly. But when I try to load `Mage::getModel("wallets/sellerrequest")->load();`  it gives error -  `Can't retrieve entity config: wallets/sellerrequest`   I am not sure whether I can do this in single module or not. I am new to magento. 
Here is my config.xml file -

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Adept_Wallets>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </Adept_Wallets>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <wallets>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Adept_Wallets</module>
                    <frontName>wallets</frontName>
                </args>
            </wallets>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <wallets>
                    <file>wallets.xml</file>
                </wallets>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <wallets>
                    <use>admin</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Adept_Wallets</module>
                        <frontName>wallets</frontName>
                    </args>
            </wallets>
        </routers>
    </admin> 
    <global>
        <models>
            <wallets>
                <class>Adept_Wallets_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>wallets_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </wallets>
            <wallets_mysql4>
                <class>Adept_Wallets_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <wallets>
                        <table>wallets</table>
                    </wallets> 
                </entities>
            </wallets_mysql4>

            <sellerrequest>
                <class>Adept_Sellerrequest_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>sellerrequest_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </sellerrequest>
            <sellerrequest_mysql4>
                <class>Adept_Sellerrequest_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <sellerrequest>
                        <table>sellerrequest</table>
                    </sellerrequest> 
                </entities>
            </sellerrequest_mysql4>

        </models>
        <resources>
            <wallets_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Adept_Wallets</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </wallets_setup>
            <wallets_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </wallets_write>
            <wallets_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </wallets_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <wallets>
                <class>Adept_Wallets_Block</class>
            </wallets>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <wallets>
                <class>Adept_Wallets_Helper</class>
            </wallets>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

And the Model file structure is -

```
Model - 
       - Sellerrequest.php
       - Wallets.php
       - Mysql4
         - Sellerrequest.php
         - Wallets.php
         - Sellerrequest
            - Collection.php
         - Wallets
            - Collection.php
```

Here is Sellerrequest.php in Model directory -

```
<?php

class Adept_Wallets_Model_Sellerrequest extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('wallets/sellerrequest');
    }
}
```

Mysql4 -> Sellerrequest.php

```
<?php

class Adept_Wallets_Model_Mysql4_Sellerrequest extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {    
        // Note that the banners_id refers to the key field in your database table.
        $this->_init('wallets/sellerrequest', 'id');
    }
}
```

Mysql4 -> Sellerrequest -> Collection.php

```
<?php

class Adept_Wallets_Model_Mysql4_Sellerrequest_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('wallets/sellerrequest', 'id');
    }
}
```

I have checked various solutions on google as well but, I am not getting what I am doing wrong. 
Same structure for the `wallets` table is working fine.

Any help is highly Appreciated !!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong model handler based on your *config.xml*.
You should call

```php
Mage::getModel("sellerrequest/sellerrequest")->load();
```

And your `_init()` function in models may also be faulty.
They should also stand **`sellerrequest/sellerrequest`** instead of `wallets/sellerrequest`/

And your `<class>` tag for the model `sallerrequest` may be wrong too.
You are stating:

```xml
<sellerrequest>
    <class>Adept_Sellerrequest_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>sellerrequest_mysql4</resourceModel>
</sellerrequest>
```

Which means Magento is going to look in the folder *app/code/local/Adept/Sellerrequest/Model/*.
Where your Model file state they are `Adept_Wallets_Model_` thus must be located in the folder *app/code/local/Adept/Wallets/Model*.

As a matter of fact this declaration is, in Magento way of doing things, totally wrong. Because with the line `<class>Adept_Sellerrequest_Model</class>` you are stating that the models of the module `Adept_Wallets` are in another module: `Adept_Sellerrequest`, which can work, but that I can not at all recommend you to do.

**But**, if you really want your module to be clear, here are how they would do it in Magento core files:

In your configuration XML file:

```xml
<config>
    <modules>
        <Adept_Wallets>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </Adept_Wallets>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <wallets>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Adept_Wallets</module>
                    <frontName>wallets</frontName>
                </args>
            </wallets>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <wallets>
                    <file>wallets.xml</file>
                </wallets>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <wallets>
                    <use>admin</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Adept_Wallets</module>
                        <frontName>wallets</frontName>
                    </args>
            </wallets>
        </routers>
    </admin> 
    <global>
        <models>
            <wallets>
                <class>Adept_Wallets_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>wallets_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </wallets>
            <wallets_mysql4>
                <class>Adept_Wallets_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <wallets>
                        <table>wallets</table>
                    </wallets> 
                    <!-- the table to connect to seller request is here -->
                    <sellerrequest>
                        <table>sellerrequest</table>
                    </sellerrequest> 
                </entities>
            </wallets_mysql4>

            <!-- do not use two models definition -->
            <!-- sellerrequest>
                <class>Adept_Sellerrequest_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>sellerrequest_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </sellerrequest>
            <sellerrequest_mysql4>
                <class>Adept_Sellerrequest_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <sellerrequest>
                        <table>sellerrequest</table>
                    </sellerrequest> 
                </entities>
            </sellerrequest_mysql4 -->
        </models>
        <resources>
            <wallets_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Adept_Wallets</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </wallets_setup>
            <wallets_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </wallets_write>
            <wallets_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </wallets_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <wallets>
                <class>Adept_Wallets_Block</class>
            </wallets>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <wallets>
                <class>Adept_Wallets_Helper</class>
            </wallets>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Then** you can use `Mage::getModel('wallets/sellerrequest')` and **also** your class names in `Adept_Wallets_Model_(...)` for `sellerrequest` are right.

Little explanation about the models in Magento

```php
Mage::getModel("module_handler/path_to_class");
```

This is how Magento get its models, but that also works for blocks when using `Mage::getBlockSingleton()` or `Mage::helper()` or `Mage::getSingleton()`, ...

So, what does this `module_handler` and `path_to_class` correspond to and how does Magento get to the right class in the right folder you may ask?

Here it goes from the start till the end:

First things first you are here requesting a model because you call `Mage::getModel()`, so Magento is going to parse the *config.xml* of all the modules to find a module with the handler: `module_handler`.

So, in your *config.xml* there should be something looking like

```xml
<config>
<!-- 
  the line above means that
  we are going to add something to the global config 
-->
    <global>
    <!-- 
      the line above means we are going to add something 
      which can be accessed by both fronted and backend elements 
    -->
        <models>
        <!-- 
          the line above means that
          we are going to add a model to the existing models 
        -->
            <module_handler>
                <!-- 
                  the line above means that
                  our new model have the handler module_handler 
                -->
                <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
                <!-- 
                  the line above states 
                  where the files of this model are located
                -->
                
                <!-- some declaration should come here -->
            </module_handler>
        <models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Ok, now Magento can get to your classes: it knows that calling **`module_handler`**`/path_to_class` have to map to `Company_Module_Model_Path_To_Class` which translate in the file in *Company/Module/Model/Path/To/Class.php*.

And for even further comprehension it knows, based on the file in *app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml* where this Module files are because you stated something like:

```xml
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends/>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

So, it knows it is a local module and it is going to look in the folder in *app/code/**local***.
So, your file is in *app/code/local/Company/Module/Model/Path/To/Class.php*.

Same if you call a simpler `Mage::getModel('module_handler/class')`
it knows the file is in *app/code/local/Company/Module/Model/Class.php*.

Comment: Thanks for the guidelines. I have made the change, but now it gives the fatal error,  Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in app/code/local/Adept/Wallets/controllers/IndexController.php on line 19

Comment: @SandyK : I edited my answer, your <class> node in the config xml may be wrong too.